# What Spanish word can be used to translate "plugin" (software term)?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

What is words can be used to translate the software term "plugin" in Spanish?

I think that Firefox has chosen "extensión", but I would like to have some other opinions on the matter.

Comment: Fundéu habló de ello en https://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/y-un-plug-in-no-es-un-complemento/ , también hay una publicación de la RAE en http://revistas.rae.es/bilrae/article/view/218/525 y Fundéu en twitter hablaba de _complemento_ o de usar _plugin_ directamente ([fuente](https://twitter.com/fundeu/status/189709079697039360))

Comment: Yo usaría **conector** (de software)

Comment: Aplicaciones auxiliares, programas auxiliares, accesorio, módulo, conector, filtros de conexión, en el contexto del browser extensión. Add-ons como elementos adicionales, complementos,  añadidos, agregados.

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_(informática)

Comment: @Jdamian, conector no me parece correcto porque deja fuera la propia funcionalidad del plugin y da a entender que el plugin es sólo la pieza que conecta un software con otro, pero que no provee ninguna funcionalidad (como un conector físico entre dos aparatos haría, por ejemplo). Otra cosa sería "conectable".

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, using the loanword, in this case "plugin" or "plug-in," makes sense--if for no other reason than to avoid confusion and ambiguities by overloading an existing word just to have it carry a new sense of meaning for something that is entirely new.  Consider that, in English itself, the word "plugin" is a word that was coined specially for this technical application.

However, in this case, the word "plugin" is spelled in a manner that is inconsistent with Spanish pronunciations.  "Ploo-heen" doesn't much resemble the original word, and would confuse anyone familiar with the original word.  So, while loanwords sometimes enrich a language with new vocabulary, in this case it seems an inferior option.

For Firefox, the word *extensión* is good, because its plugins extend its functionality.  But sometimes a plugin is not even a piece of software: it can be a new graphics card for the PC, added to the main board via a slot for the purpose. Do we still think of that as an extension?

I like cocteau´s suggestion of *módulo*.  For a piece of hardware, at least, that seems a better word.  For software, *extensión, auxiliar, suplementario,* or even *módulo* might be options to consider.

I think words like *programa* and *aplicación* should be reserved for the main software to which the plugin is added.

Comment: The points you made were excellent. Much better than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yo apuesto por

> **Complemento**. Cosa, cualidad o circunstancia que se añade a otra para hacerla íntegra o perfecta.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin on this website https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/plugin/ is defined as *a piece of software containing a group of functions that can be added to a WordPress website*.

I tried to find what the Spanish translation for Software was and all I found were these sites:

https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/spanish-word-for-c981d125d1a564c9f5738faff51d59d98711f145.html

https://www.duolingo.com/dictionary/Spanish/software/38c6e81de9516a35e9d97902e74acf26

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english-spanish/software

https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/software.html

In Wordhippo.com: How do you say software in Spanish? Answer: software

In duolingo.com: How do you say softare in Spanish? Answer: software

In collinsdictionary.com: How do you say software in Spanish? Answer: software

But in linguee.com: How do you say software in Spanish? Answer: software (most commonly used) or programa or aplicación informática (less commonly used)

You can't get any closer than programa or aplicación informática

I typed plugin in the search bar of linguee.com and this search directed me to the DeepL Translator:
https://www.deepl.com/translator?utm_source=lingueebanner1&il=en#en/es/plugin
How do you say plugin in Spanish? DeepL Translator's Answer: Plugin

I would go with Jdamian's comment, if you really want a true Spanish equivalent of the word plugin.